# pass a list of object in django form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

```
 try:
     degree = get_list_or_404(Degree,education__user__username=username)
except Http404:
     degree = Degree()
```

***degree*** will have multiple object which contains all the education details of a user. Now i want to send this `degree object` to form. I know how to pass a single instance of object.

**views.py**

```
   def profile_edit(request,username):
    profile_edit = get_object_or_404(User,username=username)
    try:
        userprofile  = get_object_or_404(UserProfile,user__username=username)
    except Http404:
        userprofile = UserProfile()
   # education = Education.objects.filter(user__username=username)
    try:
        # wanna send this in template
        degree = get_list_or_404(Degree,education__user__username=username)
    except Http404:
        degree = Degree()
    if request.user == profile_edit and request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = EditForm(request.POST,instance=profile_edit)
            form1 = EditForm1(request.POST,instance=userprofile)
            form2 = EditForm2(request.POST,instance=degree) # how to pass degree ?
            if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
                form.save()
                form1.save()
                form2.save()
                return redirect('profile_edit',username=username)
        else:
            form = EditForm(instance=profile_edit)
            form1 = EditForm1(instance=userprofile)
            form2 = EditForm2(instance=degree)
        context = {'form':form,'form1':form1,'form2':form2}
        return render(request,'userprofile/profile_edit.html', context)
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

Here is **forms.py** for **degree** :-

```
class EditForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Degree
        fields = ('degree','major','passing_year','college',)
```

Comment: A model form is for editing a single instance. If you want to edit multiple instances at once, look at formsets, specifically [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Comment: @Alasdair can you please explain how to use the model formsets in above scenario.

Comment: No, sorry, I can't write the code for you. You might find it easier if you try to start with a view that uses a single model formset, rather than add it to your view which is processing three different forms.